# HomePage not loading sometimes properly magento 2

Tags: magento2, home-page

Homepage renders like this sometimes, js merged, cache flushed dont know whats going on.

[image]

Link to the website, 911customtest.com 
If loads properly load it on private browser.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked your site and went to the console logs errors of Google chrome. Those are the errors listed.

I have experienced this one before. I forgot that the "Sign Static Files" is configured to "Yes" from the backend of the site.

Here's my suggestion. Please redeploy your website by running this command via ssh. I hope it will help you solve your problem.

Here's what you need to do. First, configure the Static file settings to "No" and redeploy the static content of the site by performing php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy on ssh.

1. go to stores>configuration>advanced>developer>static file settings and configure to no.
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Guys Just correct me if I'm wrong with my steps. And I hope this will help you fix your problem.

Thanks!

[image: Console Logs Error]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This didn't worked in my case, set static files to no and also merged css and js. Check here 911customtest.com

Comment: After those configurations did you run this from your ssh? 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: I checked your site. its working fine only there's a small warning from console debugger.

Comment: Kindly Check it on incognito browser